# bound/throttle concurrent jobs, without creating a thread-per-job

Tags: asynchronous, concurrency, f#

I want to process a collection of io-bound jobs concurrently, but bound/limit the number of outstanding (actively running) concurrent jobs.

Chunking is an easy way to increase concurrency, but creates bottlenecks if the items take varying amounts of time.

The way I found to do this is has some issues `1)`.  Is there a way do this avoiding the issues below while remaining comparably idiomatic and succinct?

`1)` use a BlockingCollection (shown below). However, this leads to a solution in which the concurrency here is generated by `boundedSize` number of "consumer" threads.  I'm looking a solution that doesn't require `boundedSize` number of threads to achieve `boundedSize` concurrent jobs. (what if `boundedSize` is very large?).  I didn't see how I could take an item, process it, and then *signal completion*.  I can only take items... and since I don't want to rip through the whole list at once, the consumer needs to run it's work Synchronously.

```
type JobNum = int

let RunConcurrentlyBounded (boundedSize:int) (start : JobNum) (finish : JobNum) (mkJob: JobNum -> Async<Unit>)  =

    // create a BlockingCollection
    use bc = new BlockingCollection<Async<Unit>>(boundedSize)

    // put async jobs on BlockingCollection
    Async.Start(async {
        { start .. finish }
        |> Seq.map mkJob
        |> Seq.iter bc.Add
        bc.CompleteAdding()
    })

    // each consumer runs it's job synchronously
    let mkConsumer (consumerId:int) = async { for job in bc.GetConsumingEnumerable() do do! job }

    // create `boundedSize` number of consumers in parallel
    { 1 .. boundedSize }
    |> Seq.map mkConsumer
    |> Async.Parallel
    |> Async.RunSynchronously
    |> ignore

let Test () = 
    let boundedSize = 15 
    let start = 1
    let finish = 50
    let mkJob = (fun jobNum -> async { 
        printfn "%A STARTED" jobNum 
        do! Async.Sleep(5000)
        printfn "%A COMPLETED" jobNum 
    })
    RunConcurrentlyBounded boundedSize start finish mkJob
```

I'm aware of TPL and mailbox processors, but thought there might've been something simple & robust, but avoids the high number of thread creation route.

Ideally there would just be one producer thread and one consumer thread; I suspect that BlockingCollection might not be the right concurrency primitive for such a case?

Comment: Why not TPL? It's quite simple to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seems as good as I'm going to get, by using `SemaphoreSlim`.

I suppose the underlying ThreadPool is really controlling the concurrency here.

```
let RunConcurrentlySemaphore (boundedSize:int) (start : JobNum) (finish : JobNum) (mkJob: JobNum -> Async<Unit>)  =

    use ss = new SemaphoreSlim(boundedSize);

    { start .. finish } 
      |> Seq.map (mkJob >> fun job -> async { 
          do! Async.AwaitTask(ss.WaitAsync())
          try do! job finally ss.Release() |> ignore
      })
      |> Async.Parallel
      |> Async.RunSynchronously
```